# Getting "chrome error communicating with the remote browser. it may have died"

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java-7, selenium-chromedriver

While automating the one scenario in chrome browser using Selenium Webdriver (Junit) as follows:

1. Click on Place Payment Button.
2. Wait for 20 Seconds
3. Retrieve the Order Number(Used GetText())

After waiting, I am get the following error:

> chrome error communicating with the remote browser. it may have died

[image]

Comment: Could you share the code as well that you have used to retrieve the Order Number?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have resolved the same issue by updating the chrome driver. Try by downloading latest version of chrome driver according to your browser version.

Comment: But I am getting this Issue on a particular operation , while retrieving text only other wise it was working fine

Comment: Even in my case also for clicking a simple button it is giving error like this. Whole automation is working fine except that button. After updating the driver its worked. So, its better to try once.

Comment: Worked for me. Get any driver version here: https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html  Just read the notes.txt files in a few different version folder to pinpoint which exact version will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this issue for around 20 days and finally resolved by updating latest Selenium Version. That means we have to use compatible Chromedriver and Selenium Version. If you use latest Chromedriver and old Selenium version, it will give this issue "- Error communicating with the remote browser. it may have died”